# sed command to format tsv file to html

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have  a tsv file which is populated by a sql query output .

I would like to send mail showing the content of this file as a html table.

Please let me know the steps to do so.

Tried with below but all the data coming in single row and single column

```
 # convert a TSV file to table format, first line is the header
head -1 testsrp.tsv | sed -e 's/\t/<\/th><th class="metric">/g' -e 's/^/<tr><th class="metric">/' -e 's/$/<\/th><\/tr>/'
cat testsrp.tsv | sed -e 3d -e 's/\t/<\/td><td class="metric">/g' -e 's/^/<tr><td class="metric">/' -e 's/$/<\/td><\/tr>/'
```

Comment: Can you give an extract of the source and how you expect it in HTML format?

Comment: @KJyothi Did you remember to wrap the HTML output in `<table>...</table>`?

Comment: In case you don't know, there are solutions to directly produce HTML pages from a SQL query's result set. [For example for Oracle DBs and their sqlplus client](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b12170/ch8.htm) ; with PostgreSQL's `psql` it's a simple `-H` switch.

Comment: my sample tsv file data is as follows

Comment: SCHEDULEID ACTVITID        NSC SCHEDULED       S
        25 PUPL_CMPGN      IND DAILY16:00      S
        24 PUPL_CMPGN      MYS DAILY15:00      S
        21 PUPL_CMPGN      MYS DAILY14:00      S
        20 PUPL_CMPGN      MYS DAILY13:00      S

Comment: It should be displayed as a table with 6 columns html table

Comment: the sample data which was provided is spooled from sql query can you please tell me how it can be exactly formatted so that I doesnot look so confused

Comment: I am redirecting output of a sql query execution to tsv . Need to send mail putting the content of the tsv file in html table format. currently tsv file has 64 rows of data and each row has 6 columns

Comment: Please edit your Q to include the useful information that have have included as comments and then delete your comments. Qs should be self-contained and complete. We need to see your sample data and required output in a readable format. Please use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. . . . .

Comment: And please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: I have the sample data in csv file or tsv file as below

Comment: I tested what you wrote, and it works if you wrap it in `<table>` tags (+1 @ruud-helderman). Or maybe your "tsv" actually has spaces instead of tabs?